# Is there a way to add a text label outside a node in tikz-qtree?

Tags: tikz-qtree

Having text labels inside nodes in trees drawn by tikz-qtree is straightforward, but is it possible to also have a label outside the node? For example, a node with letter A inside it, and letter B outside it on its left/right-hand-side?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add labels to nodes, which are nodes themselves, such as in this `tikz-qtree` line:

```
[.\node [label=right:B] {A};]
```

There are further placement options, such as `left`, `above`, `below`, `above left`, ... and style options, such as `label={[red]right:B}`.